# Windows Store App Calendar XAML Control

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, custom-controls, windows-store-apps

I am looking for a calendar control to display a schedule. Although the native app provides this feature which looks like this [image: Calendar screenshot]

I do want to include this in my own app. **Are there any (preferrably free) controls which I could use?**

Answer (score 1):

Calendar control is available in Syncfusion WinRT studio.

http://www.syncfusion.com/products/winrt/controls

Answer (score 0):

There is a calendar control I ported from Silverlight Toolkit [here](http://winrtxamlcalendar.codeplex.com/), but I think it only supports month-view and not a daily schedule. I might be wrong though since I never used it.

Answer (score 0):

we ship Calendar control: http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/CalendarWinRT/
The trial version is free, so you can take a look. The current version only supports month view and has no embedded support for Scheduling object model. So, the most of job should be done from your code and there are some layout limitations (you can't show multiday event over several days as in native calendar). Here is a sample of interactive calendar with ability to create, edit and remove appointments: http://our.componentone.com/samples/winrtxaml-calendardata.
Making fully-functional calendar with scheduling support is still in our todo list.